# How to disable root login from login prompt but allow switching to root

Tags: linux, root, login-screen

I would like disable logging in as root on the login prompt but it should be possible to 'su' to root, give password and login.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of oracle linux is this? Their docs say that oracle linux comes with `root` login disabled and `sudo` configured.

Comment: if your system is configured as @terdon suggests, then leave root disabled and use `sudo -i` instead of `su`

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41840/effect-of-entries-in-etc-securetty) which talks about the `/etc/securetty` file.

Obstensibly, if `/etc/securetty` is present on the system, but empty (quoting):

> If /etc/securetty exist and is empty, root access will be restricted
>   to single user mode or programs that are not restricted by
>   pam_securetty (i.e. su, sudo, ssh, scp, sftp)

For `ssh` and friends you will have to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and add or uncomment a `PermitRootLogin yes` line.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent users from logging in as root directly, edit the `/etc/passwd` file, changing the shell from `/bin/bash` to `/sbin/nologin`. Modify the `/etc/sudoers` file using `visudo` to grant specific users authority to perform administrative tasks.

Hint copied from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/tips-harden-oracle-linux-1695888.html).

Comment: I am running Oracle Linux 6.3. i actually had to setup sudo in /etc/sudoers, it wasn't setup by default. Now i would like to not allow any logins for root from the login: prompt,

Answer (score 1):

To disable root login modify the shell for root in `/etc/passwd` to `/sbin/nologin` either directly using an editor or using `usermod -s /sbin/nologin root`

Alternatively you can use `passwd -l root`

Once you're logged in as a regular sudoer (user with sudo privileges) you can access a root shell by using `sudo su` or `sudo -i`

Comment: but this way it locks the account, i can't even 'su - root' .. there is this setup i saw once at a place i worked before.. where i couldn't login as root but as another user i could 'su - root' , give the password and get authenticated. that is the setup i am looking for.

Comment: perhaps try setting the root password hash to `!` to disable password login but still allow sudo login (http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow)